# how to use relationship in modal in laravel 5.2?

Tags: laravel-5

I am trying to create relationship between tables in modal in laravel 5.2,
but don't know how to implement this.

I have tried to use models but no success.

here is the code i have tried

```
public function assignee() { 

    return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\User', 'stocktake_batch_assignee', 'user_id'); 

}
```

Comment: please provide your tried code

Comment: _modals_, You mean models ??

Comment: found the problem, it should be App\Models\User

not App\Model\User

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use App\Models\User not App\Model\User

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a model name Job and another model User like so..

Your Job model.

```
class Job extends Model {

    public function assignee() { 

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\User', 'stocktake_batch_assignee', 'user_id'); 
    }
}
```

Your User model.

```
class User extends Model {    

}
```

Now if want all jobs with related user from your controller you can do..

```
public function getJobs(){

    $jobs = Job::with('assignee')->all();

    //Now return view or something..

}
```